# Custom formatting numbers in axes of QCustomPlot

Tags: qt, qcustomplot

I would like to set the formatting of numbers in axes of QCustomPlot. I know how to deal with decimal precision, but have no idea, how to use spaces instead of commas in case of large numbers.

I would like numbers to look like this:

```
1.045   (decimals separated with a dot)
1 000  (thousands separated with space, currently I get 1,000)
```

there is a method QCPAxis::setNumberFormat, which seems to not be what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subclass QCPAxisTicker and reimplement [getTickLabel](http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPAxisTicker.html#a8201eb4aa8be192bf786b126eb5ee089) method

I couldn't find locale that would do spaces as group separator and dot as decimal point so i instead used QString replace function to make "custom separators".

Quick and dirty example:

```
QString getTickLabel (double tick, const QLocale &locale, QChar formatChar, int precision) {
    QLocale l;
    QString number = l.toString(tick, 'g', 15);
    number.replace(l.decimalPoint(), ".");
    number.replace(l.groupSeparator(), " ");

    return number;
}
```

input:

```
1000000.1411
```

output:

```
"1 000 000.1411"
```